# Trying to restore Drive that I accidentally used DD on

Tags: boot, hard-drive, dd, gpt, gdisk

I was attempting to use the DD command to create a bootable Ubuntu server USB. By accident, I ran the command to my boot drive. It ran for a few minutes, then I noticed and pressed control+z to halt to process. The system seemed to run fine afterwards, and later I restarted the PC.

Now my system will no longer boot. When I booted into a live USB and checked the drive, I see the following image.

[image]

Ubuntu server iso has its own partition along with the efi partition, another read only partition, and a 120GB partition that used to hold my root and home directory.

Upon seeing this, I did some research and decided to run gdisk to attempt and recover the partition table of the GPT drive. The commands I attempted to use to accomplish this can be seen in this pastebin. https://pastebin.com/8LwG1ee4

To summarize the pastebin, I attempted to restore the drive with the backup partition table using gdisk's recovery mode. I was told that the secondary pointer did not point to the back table, so I altered it and then attempted to restore the table. After doing that, the drive remained the same as in the previous image and is unmountable.

Is my data beyond reasonably saving? Or is there a method I may be missing? Please let me know if there are any issues with this question or if anyone needs more information.

Comment: You seem to be well past partition repair, and well into data-recovery. Look up how to use photorec and testdisk. It may take a long time to recover much. If your data is vital or particularly valuable, then skip to paid data recovery services. You have learned a lesson about the value of proper backups.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thankfully, this was a fairly new boot disk without anything irreplaceable on it. Hadn't gotten around to doing a system backup yet. Thank you for the advice